# Linux Glib installation without gettext?

Tags: linux, gettext, glib

Is it possible to install Glib ( in my case 2.33.3) without gettext? I searched via google, but I just found some commends that it should be possible. But nobody describes it.

Purpose: I need to install udev. That requires glib.

Can someone help me?

Note: I use a customized 2.6.36 Kernel on a Target board

Comment: What is your operating system? What would you like to do?

Comment: @ymn I edited my question. One more question: gettext is just for "translate" strings, right ?  (more or less)

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be one of requirements.  So, No, you must have a gettext package installed or have gettext support in your C library.  Here is the code taken from `configure.ac`.

```
dnl
dnl gettext support
dnl

ALL_LINGUAS="`grep -v '^#' "$srcdir/po/LINGUAS" | tr '\n' ' '`"
AC_SUBST([CONFIG_STATUS_DEPENDENCIES],['$(top_srcdir)/po/LINGUAS'])
GLIB_GNU_GETTEXT

if test "$gt_cv_have_gettext" != "yes" ; then
  AC_MSG_ERROR([
*** You must have either have gettext support in your C library, or use the
*** GNU gettext library. (http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/gettext.html
])
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have either have gettext support in your C library, or you are required to use the gettext library. I assume that you don't have gettext in either of them, so depends on your choice.

http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/gettext.html

Comment: @Peter you have a PowerPc correct? Did you install glibc manually, if so it would be interesting to know if you built it with the parameter "--without-included-gettext"

Comment: Yes I installed it manually (actually glib-2.32.4), but without any parameter.

Comment: @Peter have you got the following program in your compiled bin folder "glib-gettextize" ?

Comment: If you mean that there should be `glib-gettextize` in the `/bin/` directory, than the answer is No. Why?

Comment: Well it depends, when you do the ./configure ./make than there should be a compiled binary somewhere in target directory, if you have built it with gettext than this program should be visible